# Powershell; Network Share MSU Deployments via GPO

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

Recently, my company had an issue with our SCCM deployments due to the WMI repository became corrupt and we've found a KB article to resolve this issue, but we need to deploy it to 700+ systems that are already in the field. We've decided that the best solution is to deploy the KB article via GPO Powershell. I've tweaked some of the code below, but when the GPO runs it doesn't do anything. When we run it stand alone, it prompts a wusa error giving the options to use wusa and fails.

Can someone poke through the code and see what I'm missing that causing the failure?

I'm certainly open to suggestions that could clean the code up as well.

Variables

$path - directy script was run from.
\systemname\Sources\Software\WMI HotFix\

$msu - current windows udpate

$update - array of file name spilt by '-'

$kbart - current update KB name

$Hotfix - result returned during installed check

$command - command to install update

$parameters - command plus the parameters to the install command '\quiet \norestart'

$install - process to start installation

$OS - Current OS version

$folder - current folder of under path that contains the udpates.

kb2617858\win7\x64

kb2617858\win7\x86

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

function Install-MSU($path)
{    

# spilt file name to get KB artical number
$update = $msu.Name -Split'-'
$kbart = $update[1]

# check if update is already installed
$HotFix = Get-HotFix -id $kbart -ea 0

# run if update is not installed
if($HotFix -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host "Installing $kbart"
    $command = "`"" + "$path\$msu" + "`""
    $parameters = $command + " \quiet \norestart"
    $install = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "wusa",$parameters )
    $install.WaitForExit()
    }

# run if update is installed
else
    {
    Write-Host "Update $kbart installed"
    }
}
} 
# set $path to network share directory location
$path = "\\systemname\Sources\Software\HotFixes"

# set $OS to current OS
$OS = gwmi -query "select Caption, OSArchitecture from win32_OperatingSystem"

# Win7 x86 or x64
if($OS.Caption -match 'Windows 7')
{
if($OS.OSArchitecture -match '64-bit')
{
$folder = 'kb2617858\win7\x64'
$path = "$path\$folder"
Install-MSU($path)
}
else
{
$folder = "kb2617858\win7\x86"
$path = "$path\$folder"
Install-MSU($path)
}
}
else
{

}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

function Install-MSU($path) {
    # spilt file name to get KB artical number
    $update = $msu.Name -Split'-'
    $kbart = $update[1]

    # check if update is already installed
    $HotFix = Get-HotFix -id $kbart -ea 0

    # run if update is not installed
    if($HotFix -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Installing $kbart"
        $command = "`"" + "$path\$msu" + "`""
        $parameters = $command + " \quiet \norestart"
        $install = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "wusa",$parameters )
        $install.WaitForExit()
    } else {
    # run if update is installed
        Write-Host "Update $kbart installed"
    }
}

# set $path to network share directory location
$path = "\\systemname\Sources\Software\HotFixes"

# set $OS to current OS
$OS = gwmi -query "select Caption, OSArchitecture from win32_OperatingSystem"

# Win7 x86 or x64
if($OS.Caption -match 'Windows 7'){
    if($OS.OSArchitecture -match '64-bit'){
        $folder = 'kb2617858\win7\x64'
        $path = "$path\$folder"
        Install-MSU($path)
    } else {
        $folder = "kb2617858\win7\x86"
        $path = "$path\$folder"
        Install-MSU($path)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nathan, thank you for your reply. However, I'm getting the following error when I execute your revised version.    Get-HotFix : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Id'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument t
null or empty and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\username\desktop\deploy-kb2617858.ps1:26 char:29
+     $HotFix = Get-HotFix -id <<<<  $kbart -ea 0
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-HotFix], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHotFixComman

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my own problem. I didn't notice that I was using \quiet and \norestart, when the parameter should be /quiet and /norestart.

Below is the final script if anyone in the future has a need for it.

Variables

$path - directy script was run from. \\systemname\Sources\Software\WMI HotFix\

$msu - current windows udpate

$update - array of file name spilt by '-'

$kbart - current update KB name

$Hotfix - result returned during installed check

$command - command to install update

$parameters - command plus the parameters to the install command '\quiet \norestart'

$install - process to start installation

$OS - Current OS version

$folder - current folder of under path that contains the udpates.

kb2617858\win7\x64

kb2617858\win7\x86

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

function Install-MSU($path)
{    

# get updates in folders
$msus = ls -Path $path *.msu -Recurse

# loop through updates
foreach ($msu in $msus)
{

# spilt file name to get KB artical number
$update = $msu.Name -Split'-'
$kbart = $update[1]

# check if update is already installed
$HotFix = Get-HotFix -id $kbart -ea 0

# run if update is not installed
if($HotFix -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host "Installing $kbart"
    $command = "`"" + "$path\$msu" + "`""
    $parameters = $command + " /quiet /norestart"
    $install = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "wusa",$parameters )
    $install.WaitForExit()
    }

# run if update is installed
else
    {
    Write-Host "Update $kbart installed"
    }
    }
}

# set $path to network share directory location
$path = "\\servername\Sources\Software\HotFixes"

# set $OS to current OS
$OS = gwmi -query "select Caption, OSArchitecture from win32_OperatingSystem"

 # if OS is windows 7
if($OS.Caption -match 'Windows 7')
{
if($OS.OSArchitecture -match '64-bit')
{
$folder = 'kb2617858\win7\x64'
$path = "$path\$folder"
Install-MSU($path)
}
else
{
$folder = "kb2617858\win7\x86"
$path = "$path\$folder"
Install-MSU($path)
}
}
else
{

}
```